# Tag suggestion: forward/reverse genetics

Tags: discussion, tags

I think it would be helpful to have [forward-genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-genetics) and [reverse-genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-genetics) tags.

1. These are well-known concepts used informatively by researchers.
2. They are more fine-grained than `genetics` alone.
3. They could be useful to distinguish the "basic" questions about fundamentals of genetics (eg. Punett squares and Mendelian laws) from more technical questions explicitly dealing with specific approaches (mutation screens and GWAS).
4. To a person who knows what these terms mean (which should be most biologists) they effectively, precisely and concisely convey what the question is about.

For instance, I would have tagged [the question I asked recently](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16289/how-can-a-yac-be-screened-against-a-cdna-library-and-a-cosmid-library-of-genomic) with [forward-genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forward-genetics) (but I lack the rep needed to create new tags).

Comment: Also, note that you now have the tag creation privilege (rep > 150).

Comment: @fileunderwater Thanks, for some reason I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonable suggestion and I have now added the tag to your question. Feel free to suggest a tag wiki entry for it: [biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/965](https://biology.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/965)
.

Do you have any suggestions for questions where [reverse-genetics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-genetics) is suitable? I don't think that tags can be created without being attached to a question.

Comment: Much to my surprise, I couldn't find any questions about mutation screens. How about I ask/answer a question, "What is the difference between forward and reverse genetics?"

Comment: I decided to ask https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/what-is-tilling . Hopefully it's not too broad (I am open to rewriting).

Comment: @Superbest You could ask the first Q as well, as a community resource, and also answer it yourself if you feel that you can give a good summary.